# Gridview with TEXT AND IMAGE in the same cell

Tags: asp.net, image, gridview

I'm trying to make a chat on an asp.net page.
I thought about using a gridview so that it's easy use a datatable and add some text. 
Lately I've been asked to put some emoticons. So now I'm in need to know if I can put text AND images in the same cell.

I've seen some other people adding text in a cell and image in another cell but never text AND images in the same cell

If not possible is there any other solution or workaround?
thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use TemplateField:

```
<asp:gridView...>

        <columns>

           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MyColumn">

          <ItemTemplate>

               <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#
                          Bind("YourCellText") %>'></asp:Label>

                 <img src='<%#Bind("your image url")%>'/>
               </ItemTemplate>

           </asp:TemplateField>
        </columns>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what sort of data you are populating into your datatable. As you mentioned the word chat, I guess it's something like this.

```
var sampleData = "<p>Hello World <img src='http://placehold.it/100x100' /></p>";
```

If so, you can use an `asp:Literal` inside an `ItemTemplate` to achieve the desired result.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Chats">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="Chats" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>'>
        </asp:Literal>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle emoji you need to able to insert them as well as display them.  such that what is rendered looks something like this:

```
    <p>This is some text followed by an emoticon 
       ##EmoteMarker## and 
       some more text.</p>
```

Where `##EmoteMarker##` is translated by your code to render something similar to this:

```
    <img src="images/emoji/smiley.png"/>
```

on databind.

Now the trick is to determine where do the images reside?

If your chat users are using some intranet or if the chat program is web based then you can use a basic embedded image in the text and just make sure the html is properly encoded/decoded in the gridview.

however if the app is say smartphone based or is a standalone app then it's likely the emoji are stored local to the device in which case the Marker mus be translated to use local resources of the app rather than a central repository of images

Or...maybe it's a combination of both.

The point is that you may have to parse the text either on input to embed an html image tag or prior to display to convert a marker to a local image/sprite